Strange behavior after compiling bcache module from source code
I’m using RHEL 9.4, whose stack kernel doesn’t have bcache kernel module included and I wanted to use bcache without recompiling whole kernel or using elrepo kernels. So I tried these steps:

Dnf download running kernel source rpm, extracted source, copy drivers/md/bcache   to another location.

Download kernel-devel.

Change bcache Makefile to enable compiling out of kernel tree.

Add #define CONFIG_BCACHE in include/linux/sched.h to avoid some compiling errors.


And then, using the command make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules, no errors.
After installing bcache-tools and reboot, the module did load, but dmesg throw out segfault errors after each bcache-register, as the pic shows.
dmesg errors
But if I compile the whole kernel with bcache enabled and boot into the new kernel, no segfault.

"Add #define CONFIG_BCACHE in include/linux/sched.h" - Macros of form CONFIG_* are intended to be changed via configuring the kernel. You shouldn't change those macros just for building a module, otherwise you will create a module which is incompatible with the kernel. As a rule of thumb: nothing should be changed in the headers provided via kernel-devel package. These headers expose types and functions which actually used by the running kernel.

@Tsyvarev Did you mean that I should in the full kernel source, using kernel menuconfig to enable the module, and then compiling the module? I’ve tried that before, but the module binary cannot even be loaded, dmesg throw some “Exec format error” .

@Tsyvarev I have no idea how to load a kernel module compiled in the full kernel source into the running kernel, even the full source is the same version, it always shows “Exec format error” and some relocation value errors in dmesg.

No, I didn't mean that you need to run make menuconfig. I meant that you shouldn't build to the existing kernel a module which requires modification of the kernel's configuration. If your bcache module may work only with BCACHE configuration option enabled, then you shouldn't build that module for the kernel which has given option disabled. Attempts to "hack" such constraint by e.g. modifying include/linux/sched.h may lead to any sort of problems.
